# Python function return value reuse in another fuction

Tags: python, function

```
def function1(a,b,c):
    total_function1 = a + b + c
    return total_function1

def function2():
    total_function2 = total_function1 * 0.3
    return total_function2

def function3():
    total_function3 = total_function1 * 0.7
    return total_function3
```

I am trying to have the logic into the first function and create simple function to just apply some percentage 30% and 70%. I will use the 3 different results into specific sqlite columns.
I have search but was not able to find this specific case.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that you apply functions correctly. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just want to use the result of my first function and do some % on the second and third function. so I dont have to maintain and update the 3 functions but only the first. answer from Barmar is working - many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the function.

```
def function1(a,b,c):
    total_function1 = a + b + c
    return total_function1

def function2(a, b, c):
    total_function2 = function1(a, b, c) * 0.3
    return total_function2

def function3(a, b, c):
    total_function3 = function1(a, b, c) * 0.7
    return total_function3
```

or you could call it outside, and pass the value in:

```
def function1(a,b,c):
    total_function1 = a + b + c
    return total_function1

def function2(total_function1):
    total_function2 = total_function1 * 0.3
    return total_function2

def function3(total_function1):
    total_function3 = total_function1 * 0.7
    return total_function3

val1 = function1(1, 2, 3)
val2 = function2(val1)
val3 = function3(val1)
```

Comment: Many thanks, I have used the first code as the values are set on condition in the first function. this is working perfectly.